# Should I use Google Web Toolkit for my new webapp?

Tags: javascript, ruby, gwt

I would like to create a database backed interactive AJAX webapp which has a custom (specific kind of events, editing) calendaring system. This would involve quite a lot of JavaScript and AJAX, and I thought about Google Web Toolkit for the interface and Ruby on Rails for server side.

Is Google Web Toolkit reliable and good? What hidden risks might be if I choose Google Web Toolkit? Can one easily combine it with Ruby on Rails on server side? Or should I try to use directly a JavaScript library like jQuery?

I have no experience in web development except some HTML, but I am an experienced programmer (c++, java, c#), and I would like to use only free tools for this project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RoR is actually one of the things the GWT is made to work well with, as long as you're using REST properly.  It's in the Google Web Toolkit Applications book, and you can see a demo from the book using this kind of idea [here](http://www.gwtapps.com/?page_id=33).  That's not to say that you won't have any problems, but I think the support is definitely out there for it.

There's a neat project for making RoR/GWT easy that you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-on-rails/) (MIT license).  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet, but it looks like a good amount of thought has been put into it.  One catch is that it looks like it hasn't been fully tested with 2.1 Rails yet, just 2.0, so you may run into a few (probably minor and fixable) errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to integrate GWT with non-Java backends such as ROR, PHP etc., you should bear in mind that GWT 1.5 now supports JavaScript Overlay types. This feature lets you write classes that can be mapped over the top of native JavaScript objects to easily provide accessor methods for properties of those objects and other extended functionality.

See this link for more details:
[JavaScript Overlay Types](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/08/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-2.html)

So you could return JSON encoded data from your backend via AJAX calls, parse it into a JavaScript Object and then access the data through your GWT Java code using the overlay classes you've created. Or when you render your page you can render static config data as JavaScript Objects and read it in via this mechanism, rather than having to do an AJAX call to grab the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you know JAVA, and have somewhere you can host it (like a tomcat or glassfish container) I would recommend that much more than using Ruby for the back end. The main reason is that then you can share all of your objects, and use the built in RPC mechanism. I've done this for quite a lot of our projects and it's a huge timesaver, not to mention that the code is less error prone, because you don't convert your java objects to anything and then back again.

I have linked my GWT with Rails before, using the to_json function in Rails and then reading the JSON in GWT. It's all supported, but it is far more annoying than just doing the back end in JAVA.

Of course if you have cheap hosting, then Java containers are pretty much out of the question, in which case I would think Rails would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

GWT is very high quality with a great community. However you do need to know CSS if you want to adjust the look of things (you will) - CSS can do a lot of the layout, just like regular web if you want it to. Libraries like GWT-ext or ExtGWT can help a bit as they have stunning "out of the box" looks but for a price (extra size to your app).

Answer (score 1):

You can code everything in Java using GWT, and you can integrate existing 3rd party javascript libraries with it. It's very good. I've never used RoR much though, so can't say anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're experienced in Java but not in Javascript/CSS, then GWT is going to be a lifesaver (unless you want to learn them, of course). CSS has so many little fiddly details. It is not uncommon to spend half a day fixing a 2 pixel misalignment that only occurs in IE6.

I am not sure about how easy it would be to use ROR for the back end... It is possible, I am sure, since GWT ajax communication is just servlets. But they provide some really nice functionality for passing Java objects back and forth which you won't be able to utilize if your server isn't also using Java.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about some of [the disadvantages of GWT](http://confusion.tweakblogs.net/blog/1052/the-disadvantages-of-the-google-web-toolkit.html) recently. Mainly, the disadvantages are: long deployment cycle for changes to some parts of the application and a rather steep learning curve. As a seasoned Java programmer, the second should be less of a problem and if you use a seperate backend, the first is also mitigated (as a complete redeploy is primarily required when you change the 'server' part of the application).

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a wonderful framework with lots of potential. Keep in mind that it's still quite new, though. There are some unresolved bugs that can really annoy you, and they usually require ugly workarounds to get past. The community is great but you'll probably end up with a few problems sooner or later that Google can't answer yet.

But hey, I say go for it. The potential for GWT is awesome, and I bet it's future will be bright.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use GWT for a new project (it's pretty easy to use in an old project too).

I my experience it's very fast to learn and use. The compiled javascript code is much better than anything you could ever write by hand and it works fast too.

Another benefit is the ability to debug you're code (which is hell with javascript alone)

Answer (score 1):

This blog has inputs from many experienced users of GWT and have some great discussion points. I personally have huge experience with varied UI Frameworks. I will add my two cents. Lets look at ***fundamental*** advantages and disadvantages of GWT

**Fundamental Advantage**

GWT takes the web layer programming to JAVA. So, the obvious advantages of Java start getting into play. It will provide Object Oriented programming. It will also provide great debugging and compile time checks. Since it generates HTML and Javascript, it will also have ability to hide some complexity within its generator.

**Fundamental Disadvantage**

The disadvantage starts from the same statement. GWT takes the web layer programming to JAVA. If you know JAVA, probably you will never look out for an alternative language to write your business logic. It's self sufficient and great. But when it comes to writing configurations for a JAVA application. We use property files, database, XML etc. We never store configurations in a JAVA class file. Think hard, why is that?

This is because configuration is a static data. It often require hierarchy. It is supposed to be readable. It never requires compilation. It doesn't require knowledge of JAVA programming language. In short, it is a different ball game. Now the question is, how it relates to our discussion?

Now, lets think about a web page. Do you think when we write a web page we write a business logic? Absolutely not. Web page is just a configuration. It is a configuration of hierarchical containers and fields. We need to write business logic for the data that will be captured from and displayed on the web page and not to create the web page itself.

Previous paragraph makes a very very strong statement. This will explain why HTML and XML based web pages are still the most popular ones. XML is the best in business to write configurations. A framework must allow a clear separation of web page from business logic (the goal of MVC framework). By doing this a web designer will be able to apply his skills of visualization and artistry to create brilliant looking web pages just by configuring XMLs and without being bothered about the intricacies of a programming language. Developers will be able to use their best in business JAVA for writing business logic.

Finally, lets talk about the repercussions in direct terms. GWT breaks this principal so it is bound to fail. The cost for developing GWT application will be very high because you will need multiskill programmers to write web pages. The required look and feel will be very hard to achieve. The turn around time of modifying the web page will be very high because of unnecessary compilation. And lastly, since you are writing web pages in JAVA it is very easy to corrupt it with business logic. Unknowingly you will introduce complexities that must be avoided.

Comment: This isn't the place to hawk your technologies in broken English

Comment: Having used GWT in a big project, business setting, for 6 months I agree strongly. GWT is FAIL.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider [Grails](http://grails.org/) ("Groovy on Rails") which gives you the benefits of a Rails framework and the use of the Java VM.

Answer (score 0):

Our team recently asked the same question, and we chose to go with GWT, especially since the designer plugin made working with GWT more accessible to non-java experts on the team.  Whoever makes this choice, just beware you DON'T use the GWT Designer plugin !!  It has not been updated (in at least a year, apparently) to create a GWT application that is compatible with IE8.

Our team had almost completed our application layouts, which were working perfectly in Chrome, FF and Safari.  Then they blew up in IE.  IE 7 would load partial pages (but not composite includes), and IE8 was not even able to load up the application.  It just hung.

The designer plugin has buttons that allow the user to add CellTable widgets that are not IE compatible (CellTable, DeckPanel, Horizontal Panel, Vertical Panel, among others). These will cause intense pain when the layouts have to be re-done in java without assistance from the designer.

Experienced GWT users love it, but the designer plugin will kill you.