# Best technology option for implementing RIA with Rails as the backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, extjs, rich-internet-application

I'm working on a application that requires a feature-rich media view, including images, videos, and smooth sequencing based on capture time. The backend is currently written in Rails.

What's currently the best, most mature option for implementing RIAs with Rails on the backend? I've looked at Flex, Laszlo, and ExtJS. ExtJS is interesting to me because I'm really not a fan of pure Flash UIs, but it seems highly targeted towards business apps, not entertainment applications like this.

Any suggestions or insights from others doing similar efforts will be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second zdmytriv for that book Flexible Rails, it's awesome.  It's fairly outdated now though but lays out how simple it is to create a solid Project Management application with Flex and Rails.  Everything in there has now become "RestfulX".

Check out [RestfulX](http://restfulx.github.com/), it's a must.  The [RestfulX Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/restfulx-framework/) is very active too and they've made a lot easy.

We built [this website](http://www.josephjewell.com/) in Flex with RestfulX and it was very easy.  That application uses the Rails Paperclip gem to do image processing in a Flex admin panel like [ScrapBlog](http://www.scrapblog.com/) (Scrapblog was built in Flex), and we could use some cool layout effects built into Flex 4.  RestfulX made that pretty easy, and the gems made it even easier :p.  They have generators too like Rails so it's real easy to get up and running with a [DataGrid/CMS-like interface in 5 minutes](http://wiki.github.com/dima/restfulx/getting-started-with-restfulx-and-ruby-on-rails).

I don't know anything about the other things you've mentioned, but I do know that it's pretty fun and easy to integrate Flex with Rails now-a-days.

As a side note, you can do hardcore SEO with Flex and Rails too, thanks to [SWFAddress](http://www.asual.com/blog/swfaddress/2007/11/15/swfaddress-2-pt3-ajax-and-seo.html).  We're doing that with that site above.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Flex and also this book [Flexible Rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988509), whole book dedicated Flex with Rail cooperation. List of sample applications from the book [here](http://www.flexonrails.com/air_apps.html)

[Flexible Rails http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QysfVDlVL._SL500_AA240_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QysfVDlVL._SL500_AA240_.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about considering Ext as an option, you should really search and maybe post in their forums about others using Rails, I know there are quite a few doing so successfully.  I just ran across [this example](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68135) that seems like a pretty fully-baked app doing just that, so it's definitely possible.

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I think that saying Ext is "targeted towards business apps" is a fair general statement, in terms of the widgets that come with it out of the box.  It's highly geared toward window/form-based Ajax apps.  That said, Ext Core is very similar to jQuery and other core frameworks, and everything in Ext is built to be highly extensible (hence, "ext").  In terms of being able to build what you need off of it, it is very powerful and flexible.  You can certainly implement a flash viewer easily, and there are existing plugins that will do exactly that.

Sounds like Toby had a bad experience with Ext, but many other people enjoy it and find it very natural to code in.  The syntax definitely has a Java/C# flavor to it in some ways (although it's really hard to directly compare any JS framework to a static language), and it has roots in YUI (which is even more verbose).  For someone coming from C-ish backgrounds, it will likely feel very comfortable.  If you're more used to Python or Ruby or something else, then it might not be as enjoyable, I don't know.  Something you'd have to try for yourself.

Comment: Ext JS and Rails are great complements. And in the newest Ext JS 3.1 release, there are many options to make interacting with RESTful web services (like Rails) much more pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Google Web Toolkit yet? In my opinion it's a great way to build rich and performant web applications. The toolkit is quite mature (Google Wave is build with it) and has a lot of good tools to make development easy.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811/should-i-use-google-web-toolkit-for-my-new-webapp)'s a previous Stakoverflow post.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at WebOrb from themidnightcoders.com.  Among many features, it allows for AMF protocol for serialization of data.  It is smoking fast.

IMO, if you want a true RIA experience, you'll need to focus on either Flex or Silverlight.  There are pros and cons to each.

Answer (score 1):

I did a GWT project a while back and am working with Ext right now. I have some C# / Swing GUI experience, none in Flash.

I like Ext a lot. It looks great, and I found the programming model close enough to the C#'s and Swings of the world as to be familiar and fairly pleasant. The documentation is not excellent, but definitely good enough. For Java at least, there is a solid remoting mechanism (third party, called DJN... most likely there are others, too). A couple of minor bugs here and there.

The major negative is support. They have a forum but there are a distressingly large number of questions and problems that go unresolved. They have paid support in theory, but were sufficiently unresponsive to basic 'how does your paid support work' type questions that I was not encouraged to buy any. There is only one book that I know of, it looks promising but it is not out yet.

I found GWT impressive and had no real problems, but at the end of of the day I am much happier with Ext.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about best, but I did a project using ExtJS and hated every minute of it. Frustratingly verbose code, overly complicated programming model, confusing documentation, and difficult to make it do anything it didn't want to.

That said, it looks very awesome, has incredibly powerful widgets and the client and users loved it.

I haven't helped at all, have I?

I think if you requirements include doing anything with video and audio, you are going to need a Flash solution.

Comment: Hmm...I agree I'll need a flash video viewer, but the entire site needn't be in flash...

Comment: or use the video tag if you van afford targeting html5 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [netzke](http://www.netzke.org) -- client-server components with Sencha Ext JS and Ruby on Rails.

> Netzke is a framework that allows for a beautiful blend of client- and
>   server-side code (JavaScript and Ruby, respectively) into ready-to-use
>   GUI components. It's most useful for creating complex data-rich
>   backend applications with Ruby on Rails on the back end, and Sencha
>   Ext JS in the browser.